# Querying an arbitrary nested json in java

Tags: java

I have trying since last couple of hours but am not able to get my head around this.

Basically, there are two things, a list and a json string:

```
queryList = [ ["user"],["place",["city"]]
```

So this queryList contains the keys whose value I want to get from the following json.

Now the json string also contains the following keys:

```
  json_string = {"user":"foo", "place": {"city":"foocity"}....}
```

since "city" is present in nested format, hence queryList has [city] which is a 2D member?

So manually, i can do something like:

```
   json_string.get("user");
   json_string.getJSONObject("place").get("city");
```

But I dont want to hardcode them...
The output I am expecting is:

```
  ["foo","foocity"]
```

I am new in java and hence having a hard time think straight in this.

Thanks

Comment: Huh? What you have posted makes no sense what so ever. The first thing you show is an array that contains two arrays, the second of which contains a string and another array that contains a string. Then you have an object that is completely unrelated.

Comment: And your input is what, exactly?

Comment: @BrianRoach: err i edited the question. I hope it is bit more clearer

Comment: OK, so, where does that query list come from and in what shape?

Comment: @fge: User will specify this querylist.. querylist can either be [["user"]] or ["place",["city"] or [["user"] , ["place",["city"]]

Comment: @Fraz and not `["place", "city"]` for the second sample? In any event I have a solution for you, but forget org.json, it has no support for JSON Pointer -- however, I have, and can edit my answer accordingly. Also, do you confirm that this query list is _also_ JSON?

Comment: @fge: No, its ["place,["city"]], the reason it is like this is to make distinction that city is actually a secondary key (with place as primary key).... querylist is a List<Object> but I can change that JSON.. basically what I want to do is.. I have a json string.. Based on my query/queries, I want to return the corresponding value of those queries (in structured format)..

Comment: @Fraz OK, other question, if there is, say, `["a", [ "b", "c" ]`, does it mean both paths `/a/b` and `/a/c` should be returned?

Comment: @fge: Yeah.. That is correct

Comment: @Fraz OK, editing my answer... But this will require you to ditch org.json. Please wait ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31011/discussion-between-fge-and-fraz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution here, based on [one of my libraries](https://github.com/fge/jackson-coreutils); this library is based on [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org). It brings in support for [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901), which is necessary for the task at hand:

https://gist.github.com/fge/5688657

Contents of `query.json`:

```
[
    ["user"],
    ["place", ["city"]]
]
```

Contents of `data.json`:

```
{
    "user": "foo",
    "place": {
        "city": "foocity"
    }
}
```

Output of the gist above:

```
["foo","foocity"]
```

as expected.

Will be edited for futher explanations.